# how can i put costum image icon in project

Tags: html, css

i am working on a project in which i have to make a webpage . i want to put custom icon  `image` in web site. i writ `cod` in `head` tag but i don't know what writ it.

```html
<head><link type="image" href="ali.gpj" rel="favorit.ico"></head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean favicon (icon that is displayed on tab) than you need to put
`<link rel="icon" href="" />`  where `href` will be your path to your picture.

Comment: can i put image whit .gpj extension instead ico